# How to prevent simple CORS GET requests from accessing my Action Methods on my ASP.Net Core API Server?

Tags: c#, ajax, http, asp.net-core, cors

To illustrate my problem I used the default ASP.Net Core project setup when you create a new project with API endpoints. This is my controller with `Get` action method:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is my `Configure` method from `Startup` class (as you can see I added `app.UseCors()` at the beginning):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

By default the server is running on `https://localhost:44391/`.
Now my expectation is that with the default setup like this all CORS request that are not coming from `https://localhost:44391/` should be blocked by CORS policy. In order to verify that I did the following steps:

1. I started the server and put a breakpoint in my `Get` method
2. To simulate a cross-domain (CORS) request, I went to any randon website e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/ opened Chrome Dev Tools and run in the console the following javascript that requests my get method:
   `fetch("https://localhost:44391/weatherforecast").then(r=>r.text()).then(console.log);`
3. Now at this point I expected that the server will send a CORS error and my `Get` method will never be executed.
4. What actually happened is that breakpoint in my `Get` method was hit and the method was executed. Only after that I saw the CORS error in my browser console.

I think this behavior is wrong, because I would really like to avoid my `Get` action method being executed altogether if the request is coming from another origin.

So basically it comes down to two questions:

1. Why does ASP.Net Core CORS strategy work in this way?
2. Is there any way to setup CORS in the way that all of action methods will never be executed, unless CORS policy allows it? Or do I need to write a custom middleware for this?

Comment: By the way, CORS is enforced by the browser, not the server.

Answer (score 4):

> "What actually happened is that breakpoint in my Get method was hit
> and the method was executed. Only after that I saw the CORS error in
> my browser console... I think this behavior is wrong"

...no, this is the expected behaviour. CORS is actually enforced by the **browser**, based on the headers that the server provides it, and whether the request is subject to CORS restrictions or not.

The server cannot be sure whether the request is a cross-domain AJAX request or some other type of request (because the data in a HTTP request doesn't reliably provide that information), so it's not within its power to directly refuse the request. All it can do is set CORS headers to tell the client what to do **if** the request is actually subject to CORS restrictions.

Therefore, your request will always be executed if it reaches the server, it's only when the response, together with the headers, is returned to the browser that the browser decides whether to allow the requesting page to actually see the response or not.

To directly answer your two questions:

1. This is how CORS works in general, it's not just ASP.NET. See the explanation above.
2. No. Again, see the explanation above. (The only exception here is requests which require a pre-flight OPTIONS request, where a separate initial HTTP OPTIONS request must be made to the server - in this case, the the Action method would not be hit unless the OPTIONS request indicates that the request is permitted.)

More details are provided in this excellent resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Also in this case the request is what is considered a "simple" request so there is no OPTIONS / pre-flight request to ask if it is okay or not.

Comment: But wouldn't it make more sense to block execution of these methods on the server side too? Of the top of my head I think it leaves your API less resistant to Cross-site request forgery, and Cross-site scripting attacks, isn't that so?

Comment: "wouldn't it make more sense to block execution of these methods on the server side too"...sure, but as I already mentioned in the answer, the contents of an incoming HTTP request doesn't give the server enough information to be able to reliably do that. It can't tell exactly how the request was generated - it can't be sure if the request should be restricted by CORS or not; only the browser can know that.

Comment: I'm quite certain that if what you're proposing was possible then it would already exist because, I agree, it would be more efficient, simpler and possibly a bit more secure. Although, I see no reason that the current situation leaves you more vulnerable to CSRF or anything particularly - why do you say that exactly?

Comment: Mybe there are some catches, but  you can just check the `origin` http header ( all browsers enforse adding this header with a request) if the value of that header does not comply with CORS policy of the server just send a response back with an appropriate CORS errror. What's the point to firts execute the action method first and then send a response? malicious script may initiate a dangerous POST request from another domain, then your server will happily process it and tell the browser: "Hey buy the way you were not allowed to make that request, but no worries I processed it for you anyways"

Comment: "you can just check the origin HTTP header"...ok but the problem is that it's easy to spoof, so anyone with any determination to attack your server would find that easy to bypass. That's why the restriction is enforced by the browser, which an attacker using a CORS attack vector cannot control. And also a standard, non-AJAX request would normally not have that header anyway - so if you block based on the presence of that then you run the risk of also blocking all non-AJAX requests if they don't comply with your unusual specification.

Comment: P.S. https://www.nccgroup.com/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2017/september/common-csrf-prevention-misconceptions/ explains nicely why CORS and CSRF are not really related to each other. CORS doesn't make you any more or less vulnerable to CSRF. If you want CSRF protection, you need to add it regardless of your CORS policy (because, apart from anything else, CSRF attacks can happen with regular postbacks not just AJAX).